# Installing iOS Apps with TodayExtension Using TestFlight Not Working Correctly

Tags: testflight, ios8-today-widget

My today extension does not work (refresh) when I install a Testflight build for the second time. I need to power down/power up and the extension works correctly.

It also works ok if I delete the previous version, and install the new one from test flight.

Here are the steps:

1) Start with a device without the app
2) Install from TestFlight
3) Add the today extension widget
4) Verify that it all works ok.
5) Install again from TestFlight
6) Widget stops working
7) Power Down
8) Power Up
9) Verify that the widget works again

If I delete the app before Step 5, then the widget works perfectly without the need to do steps 7 & 8.

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I just tried to replicate what you have, and I can't seem to re-install from TestFlight. How are you doing that? All I see is "OPEN". Are you using iOS 8.1.x?

Comment: I'm seeing this, too. Have you submitted a version of your app with the Today extension since this question? Did it become unresponsive when downloaded from the App Store?